# Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f\left(X,\theta\right)\biggr|_{\theta_0}$ a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

[Related to my previous question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584510/is-textargmax-theta-f-leftx-1-cdots-x-n-right-a-random-variable) Let $X$ be a r.v. defined on $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\right)$. Let $f$ be a real-valued function, with a "parameter" $\theta \in \mathbb{R}.$ Furthermore, assume that $f$ is smooth in $\theta$. That is, for any $x$, the function $f\left(x,\cdot\right):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth.

Consider $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f\left(X, \theta\right)\biggr|_{\theta_0}$. Is this a random variable? Can we find some Borel measurable function $g$ such that $g\left(X\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f\left(X,\theta\right) \biggr|_{\theta_0}$ (almost) everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(X,\theta)$ is a random variable for each fixed $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(X,\theta) \bigg|_{\theta=\theta_0} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(X,\theta_0+1/n)-f(X,\theta_0)}{1/n}$$ is measurable as a pointwise limit of measurable mappings.